# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'class function' of undefined in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, typeerror

Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'manageChange' of undefined

I have bound the method to "this" as well. I have even tried the arrow function format to define "manageChange". It still does not work.

Please help out with identifying the issue?
Code:

```
 class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { todos: TodoData };
    this.manageChange = this.manageChange.bind(this);
  }

  manageChange(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }

  render() {
    const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(function (item) {
      return (<TodoItem key={item.id} items={item}
        handleChange={this.manageChange} />);
    }
    );
    return
    (
      <div className="app">
        {todoItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not in the definition of your `manageChange` function. It is instead in the below code

```
const todoItems=this.state.todos.map(function(item)
                {
                   return (<TodoItem key={item.id} items={item} 
                    handleChange={this.manageChange}/>);
                }
                );
```

You should change it to below and use `arrow` function instead like this

```
const todoItems=this.state.todos.map((item) => 
                {
                   return (<TodoItem key={item.id} items={item} 
                    handleChange={this.manageChange}/>);
                }
                );
```

Please note the difference in `arrow function` and `normal function`. The reference in the arrow functions is passed down to the children.

So when you define it like this; `this` keyword is passed as an reference of the class to `this.manageChange` and is not undefined.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. very new to ES6 and React and hence the confusion.

Comment: Happy to help. You can read more on ES6 features here. `http://es6-features.org`.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with map function. use arrow function in map. if you use normal function it will have it's own this which won't have manageChange function.

```
const todoItems=this.state.todos.map((item) =>
    {
                   return (<TodoItem key={item.id} items={item} 
                    handleChange={this.manageChange}/>);
    }
);
```